# Временная папка tmp Linux

Tags: c++, linux

В какой переменной окружения Linux хранит путь к папке temp\tmp?
Мне нужно программно найти путь к этой папке. Программа на C++.

Comment: Не факт что вообще в какой-то. У меня, например, под Mint и Debian такой переменной нет.

Comment: Уточните, вам нужно именно узнать путь к папке temp в системе (в таком случае, вам нужно указать, по каким критериям искать - например, эта папка должна быть указана в какой-то переменной), или программно создать временный файл в папке, предназначенной для временных файлов, и в которой этот файл гарантированно создастся? ИМХО, от этого будет зависеть, какой ответ получите.

Comment: если память не изменяет то команда set вам все покажет

Answer (score 4):

согласно стандарту [posix](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) каталогом для хранения временных файлов является [каталог `/tmp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap10.html).

но, т.к. вы спрашиваете конкретно про операционную систему *gnu/linux*, то здесь применим стандарт [fhs](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FHS), согласно которому местом для сохранения временных файлов является не только [каталог `/tmp`](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#TMPTEMPORARYFILES), но и [каталог `/var/tmp`](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#VARTMPTEMPORARYFILESPRESERVEDBETWEE). разница между ними в том, что первый обычно (но не обязательно) очищается при загрузке операционной системы.

а т.к. вы уточняете ещё и про *c++*, то вышеописанной информацией можно пренебречь ввиду наличия определённой [стандартом *posix* функции `tmpfile()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tmpfile.html) и её *c++*-аналога [std::tmpfile()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/tmpfile).

---

наличие же каких-либо переменных окружения, связанных с каталогом для хранения временных файлов, насколько мне известно, ни одним из упомянутых стандартов не требуется.

Answer (score 3):

Если она определена, то `TMPDIR`.
Иначе используют каталог по умолчанию `/tmp`

Comment: Значит достаточно обратиться к /tmp?

Comment: @Сергей, для чего? Чтобы, например, создать временный файл/каталог, вообще никакая информация ни об окружении, ни о пути, не нужна. Ибо [man tempfile](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?category=1&russian=2&topic=tempfile) и аналогично для программного использования.

Comment: @Сергей, расположение `\tmp` (как, впрочем, и ряда других папок) зафиксировано в *[Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FHS)*.

Comment: @Сергей, как заметили выше - не понятно, для чего вам нужно обратиться к временной папке =) Ещё так же может использоваться каталог `/var/tmp`.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала имеет смысл проверять переменную окружения `TMPDIR`. Если та существует и является путём - то использовать её.

В `win32 api` посмотрите на метод `GetTempPathW`. (упомянуто для полноты картины)

Если не существует, то стандартный заголовок `stdio.h` может объявить `P_tmpdir`.

Если ничего не помогло, то можно воспользоваться стандартным `/tmp`, но только как последнее средство.

PS: ответ основан на реализации [функции `sys_get_temp_dir` в php](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/6053987bc27e8dede37f437193a5cad448f99bce/main/php_open_temporary_file.c#L215).

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл функцию, которая позволяет взять путь к папке c временными файлами как в Windows, так и в Linux.

```
std::experimental::filesystem::temp_directory_path();
```